# How to continuously update DataTable with new data streaming in?

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I am dynamically updating my DataTable with data coming in over a websocket from my server. I would like it to only display 20 or so rows of data and after 20 rows is reached to start deleting the first row at the same rate it adds a new row so that the table is continuously updating with the latest 20 data points streaming in. So its like a continuous feed. I need to use DataTable and not dataTable so fnDeleteRow will not work. Is there any other builtin in function I can use to achieve this affect, either to continually delete the first row or another function altogether that will allow for the same affect?

Comment: For version 1.10 and higher, you can use [`remove()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().remove())

Comment: `$('#example').dataTable().fnDeleteRow()` would still work, even if you have initialised with `DataTable`